# Put bootstrap button in middle of section

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css

this is html code,using Bootstrap 3:

```
<section class="col-md-12 section2 "> 
  <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-1 col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1 col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
        <button ><a href=""class="sec2Text ">test</a></button>
      </div> 
    </div>
</section>
```

Css clases:

```
.section2{
 height:310px;
 max-height:310px;
}

a.sec2Text{
 color:#000;
 font-size:55px;
}
```

First of all, I try to put button in middle of section for all screens. Try with: margin:auto;, and in that case get horizontaly align,but verticaly no(button stay on top od section). Text-center, also don't fix problem...

I probably can do this with @media for each screen, but would like to know if there any universal solution..

Tnx,
P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<div style="display:table; height:310px; width: 100%;">
  <div style="display:table-cell;vertical-align:middle;">
    <button style="text-align:center;">Text Content</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

For more check this out : [how to center in css](http://howtocenterincss.com/)

Comment: Hi,tnx for time...Yeah,this solve problem just with one update: <div style="display:table; height:310px;width:100%;" class="text-center"> need width:100% and all is fine...Tnx

Comment: @pavlenko Happ to help :)

Answer (score 0):

Use this css below:

```
.section2 button{
    display:table;
    margin:auto;
}
.section2 button a{
    display:block; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will solve your problem

```
<section class="col-md-12 section2 "> 
  <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-10 text-center col-xs-offset-1 col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1 col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
        <button ><a href=""class="sec2Text ">test</a></button>
      </div> 
    </div>
</section>
```